# Custom post Sign-in page and Sign-out page for Microsoft Identity platform

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

I would like to use Microsoft Identity platform in my ASP.NET Core.NET 6 application with a custom sign in and sign out page.

In my case, i don't want to redirect automatically user to Microsoft sign in page but to my custom sign in page (that contain login button).Same for signout page.
I am using `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();
```

how can I change the default behaviour ?

Comment: This is explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity)

Comment: Oh wait, you want to replace the **_Microsoft_** sign in page? Is that even possible? I don't think so, as this would make it easy to spoof it, which would be a security risk.

Comment: i want to show a home page that contain login button , the redirection to microsoft login page achieved when user click on the login button..

Comment: Does this page of the docs work [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore). Bottom line, read the docs, search the docs, etc. Most info is in the docs.

Comment: thank you for the link , i will try to add  OpenID Connect middleware

Comment: Fisrtly, you may need a filter to check if the user signed in already, if false then redirect to your own login in page, on that page, you may add a button which indicate user to click it then they can sign in with microsoft account, this button may be set to send request to an action which has `[Authorize]` attribution, then it will redirect to microsoft sign in page. And as you know that you need to define a call back path when using azure ad authentication, then all your requirement met.

Comment: @TinyWang the Microsoft identity for asp.net has its own midfleware for that,  don't need to double up on that, just configure it correctly. And I would add the authorize attribute on the controller class level, which spares you from having to add it to every action (and accidently forgetting one, which has happened in production for companies I know).

Comment: thank you sir, since I failed to find a sample for that so I do a 'custom' test in my side and shared it.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I integrate azure ad in my asp.net core MVC project:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
    // Add the Microsoft Identity UI pages for signin/out
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
}
```

And I set the default home page to my HelloController, it will reder hello/index.cshtml to the page, with a button `<a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home">Home</a>`

And in my `HomeController.cs`, it has `[Authorize]` annotation on the controller, so when I didn't  sign in with azure ad, it will redirect to microsoft sign in page. Then since I set the callback path as the `home/index.cshtml`, after sign in, I will go to `home/index.cshtml`.

My home controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```